# How do you call an API in php?

Tags: php, curl

I know this has been answered many times. However, in my case I need to connect first with a host then make an tunnel. I just copied this from another. Here it is:

```
$fp = ssh2_connect('xxx.xxx.xx.xxx', xxxx);

if (ssh2_auth_password($fp, 'username', 'password')) {
            echo "Authentication Successful!<br>";
            $connection = ssh2_tunnel($fp, 'xxx.xx.xx.xx', xx);

            if($connection){
                echo "Authentication Successful!<br>";

                $service_url ='Sample URL';

                $curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1) or die("Curl Error TRANSFER");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE) or die("Curl Error SSL");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

                $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
                echo $curl_response."<br><br>";

                if ($curl_response === false) {
                    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
                    echo curl_getinfo($curl) . '<br/>';
                    echo curl_errno($curl) . '<br/>';
                    echo "Curl Error: ".curl_error($curl) . '<br/>';

                    curl_close($curl);
                    die('error occured during curl exec. Additional info: ' . var_export($info));
                }
                else{
                    echo "Success";
                }

            } else {
                die('Authentication Failed...');
            }
                } else {
                die('Authentication Failed...');
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Matts, Did you just answer yourself in the question? - It is totally ok to question and answer yourself, please do it in that format: a clear question posted as question and an answer posted as an answer to that question. - Otherwise I don't get the question, do you have a problem with that code?

Comment: Oh sorry haha it is my first time to post here. Anyway my question is what am I doing wrong in this code? Cause I found this code in a forum. They said it's suppose to work. But it's not :(

Comment: @Matts, have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ?

Answer (score 0):

`They said it was suppose to work.`
Have you tried fixing it yourself? Most people here frown upon someone just grabbing some code and then asking for help without having a clue as to what is going on.

Besides... You need to provide more information as to what the error is.
There are several spots that the script returns a value... Where is it returning for you?
`Authentication Failed...`, `Curl Error:`, `error occured during curl exec`, or was it something else?

I just ran this on my server fine. Had no issues.

Comment: Then your SSH and tunnel are working fine. I dont know if its because that IP is in-accessable from the outside (perhaps that is the reason you want to tunnel) but it states the port is closed. So I would first check that you can, indeed, connect to that server on that port.

Comment: And of course I just remember my IP range info. 10.x.x.x is a private IP. Ha. Ignore the first half of my comment. My suggestion still stands. Ensure that the port is actually open.

Comment: Oh and one more thing. What if the tunnel does require a password? I tried to access that IP address with PUTTY and I got in. However, the tunnel did require a password. How do I place that into code?

Comment: It shouldn't be requiring any additional credentials. The process is `ssh2_connect($host,$port)`,`ssh2_auth_password($resource,$user,$pass)` (creds go there), `ssh2_tunnel($another_host,$port)`. If a second set of credentials IS required, then I might be able to update the answer with a solution... But perhaps there is a better method than using work-arounds.

Comment: you mean like file_get_contents()?

Comment: I doubt `file_get_contents()` will help you much if you need to authenticate twice. I feel like you need to finish explaining what is going on. Edit your original question, adding in the important details (error you had, end goal/what you are trying to accomplish, what other things you may have tried, why do you need two machines, are you able to do this with one, ect) and I will continue to help you. You need a higher score on this question. As of right now, with a score of -4, this question will soon be closed/removed and you will not be able to get help.